# php+mysql: how to read several time results of query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i execute a query on my database, and i need to read results several times. I have write this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE true");
foreach ($my_array as $current) {
    //iterate over mysql resutls
    while ($current_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now, when i've read for first time all rows of query, how i can start again to first row for next foreach iteration?

Answer (score 2):

You can do as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE true");
foreach ($my_array as $current) {
    //iterate over mysql resutls
    while ($current_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                
        //do something
    }
}

mysql_data_seek($result,0);
```

and then continue looping again !!

https://www.php.net/mysql_data_seek

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE true");
$allResults = array();

while ($current_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                
   $allResults[] = $current_row;
}

foreach ($my_array as $current) {
    // do something with $allResults
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use mysqli, not mysql.
Then, there are "fetch" all functions.

Depending on how much results you have and how much memory should decide if this is a wise course of action.

Or you use the result of Abhik Chakraborty, that reduces memory load, but increases harddisk load.

I'd suggest you test with execution times.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE true");
$Allresults = mysqli_fetch_all ($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($Allresults as $current) {
    //iterate over mysql resutls
    while ($current_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using PDO, this will make it a lot easier for you...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$result = $db->query("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE true");
$arrayOfResults = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//now you can use $arrayOfResults however many times you want....

foreach($arrayOfResults as $row){
     //do something
}

foreach($arrayOfResults as $row){
     //do something else...
}
```